# Which Optimization method to use?

Tags: optimization

I have a non-function (not in closed form) that takes in a few parameters (about 20) and returns a real value. A few of these parameters are discrete while others are continuous. Some of these parameters can only be chosen from a finite space of values.

Since I don't have the function in closed form, I cannot use any gradient based methods. However, the discrete nature and the boxed constraints on a few of those parameters restrict even the number of derivative free optimization techniques at my disposal. I am wondering what are the options in terms of optimization methods that I can use.

Comment: So you want to estimate the function and its extrema too? Or you have a black box operating as a function which you need to strategically query to determine the extremum?

Comment: I have a black box operating as a function and I need to strategically query it in order to determine the optimum. Of course, I am not looking for the global maximum but anything that is smarter than a grid search over a space of parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bayesian optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization) is a principled way of sequentially finding the extremum of black-box functions. What's more, there a numerous software packages that make it easy, such as [BayesOpt](https://bitbucket.org/rmcantin/bayesopt) and [MOE](http://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2014/07/introducing-moe-metric-optimization-engine-a-new-open-source-machine-learning-service-for-optimal-ex.html). Another flexible Bayesian framework that you can use for optimization is [Gaussian processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process): [Global Optimisation with Gaussian Processes](http://ml.dcs.shef.ac.uk/gpss/gpss13/talks/Sheffield-GPSS2013-Osborne.pdf)