# How to make scipy.optimize.basinhopping find the global optimal point

Tags: optimization, scipy

## Question

Try to find the global optimal point of the function (reading [Python for finance 2nd edition - Chapter 11. Mathematical Tools](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-finance/9781492024323/ch11.html)).

```
def fm(p):
    x, y = p
    return (np.sin(x) + 0.05 * x ** 2
          + np.sin(y) + 0.05 * y ** 2)
```

[image]

[scipy.optimize.basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#scipy.optimize.basinhopping) says it finds the global minimum.

> Find the global minimum of a function using the basin-hopping algorithm

However, it looks it does not find the global optimal point. Why is this and how can make it find the global optimal?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sco 
from pylab import plt, mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

plt.style.use('seaborn')
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
%matplotlib notebook

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 50)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = fm((X, Y))

optima = sco.basinhopping(
    fo,
    (-10, 10),
    stepsize=0.1
)
# Optimal 
optima['x'] = np.append(optima['x'], fm((optima['x'][0], optima['x'][1])))
optima
```

**Result**

```
                        fun: 3.5447966927667616
 lowest_optimization_result:       fun: 3.5447966927667616
 hess_inv: array([[9.01401735e-01, 1.68119491e-03],
       [1.68119491e-03, 2.84089686e+00]])
      jac: array([2.98023224e-08, 2.98023224e-08])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 24
      nit: 5
     njev: 6
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([-1.42755175,  9.67888407])
                    message: ['requested number of basinhopping iterations completed successfully']
      minimization_failures: 0
                       nfev: 2516
                        nit: 100
                       njev: 629
                          x: array([-1.42755175,  9.67888407,  3.54479669])
```

Plot:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Function
surf = ax.plot_surface(
    X, Y, Z, 
    rstride=2, 
    cstride=2,
    cmap='coolwarm', 
    linewidth=0.5,
    antialiased=True
)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('f(x, y)')

# Optima
ax.plot(
    [optima['x'][0]], [optima['x'][1]], [optima['x'][2]], 
    color='r', marker='X', markersize=15
)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
```

[image]

### Brute

```
If used [scipy.optimize.brute][5], it may be able to find near point.

OX = []
OY = []
output = True
def fo(p):
    x, y = p
    z = np.sin(x) + 0.05 * x ** 2 + np.sin(y) + 0.05 * y ** 2
    if output == True:
        #print('%8.4f | %8.4f | %8.4f' % (x, y, z))
        OX.append(x)
        OY.append(y)
    return z

optima = sco.brute(
    fo, 
    (
        (-10, 10.1, 2), # Step X from -10 to 10.1 by interval 2
        (-10, 10.1, 2)  # Step Y from -10 to 10.1 by interval 2
    ), 
    finish=None
)  
OZ = fm((np.array(OX), np.array(OY)))

# Optimal 
optima = np.append(optima, fm((optima[0], optima[1])))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Function
surf = ax.plot_surface(
    X, Y, Z, 
    rstride=2, 
    cstride=2,
    cmap='coolwarm', 
    linewidth=0.5,
    antialiased=True
)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('f(x, y)')

# Brute computation tack
ax.plot(np.array(OX), np.array(OY), np.array(OZ), ls="--", color='k', linewidth=0.5)

# Optima
ax.plot(
    [optima[0]], [optima[1]], [optima[2]], 
    color='r', marker='X', markersize=15
)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
```

[image]

### SHGO

[scipy.optimize.shgo](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.shgo.html#scipy.optimize.shgo) seems to work, too.

> Finds the global minimum of a function using SHG optimization.

```
optima = sco.shgo(
    fo,
    [(-10, 10), (-10, 10)]
)
# Optimal 
optima['x'] = np.append(optima['x'], fm((optima['x'][0], optima['x'][1])))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Function
surf = ax.plot_surface(
    X, Y, Z, 
    rstride=2, 
    cstride=2,
    cmap='coolwarm', 
    linewidth=0.5,
    antialiased=True
)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('f(x, y)')

# Optima
ax.plot(
    [optima['x'][0]], [optima['x'][1]], [optima['x'][2]], 
    color='r', marker='X', markersize=15
)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
```

[image]

### Clarification

Even though it is  "global Optimization", are there conditions or limitations to consider to make sure they find the global optimal?

> [Global Optimization](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#global-optimization)
>   **basinhopping(func, x0[, niter, T, stepsize, …])** 
>   Find the global minimum of a function using the basin-hopping algorithm
>   **brute(func, ranges[, args, Ns, full_output, …])** 
>   Minimize a function over a given range by brute force.
>   **differential_evolution(func, bounds[, args, …])**
>   Finds the global minimum of a multivariate function.
>   **shgo(func, bounds[, args, constraints, n, …])**
>   Finds the global minimum of a function using SHG optimization.
>   **dual_annealing(func, bounds[, args, …])** 
>   Find the global minimum of a function using Dual Annealing.

### References

- [Python for finance 2nd edition - Chapter 11. Mathematical Tools](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-finance/9781492024323/ch11.html)
- [Which Optimization method to use?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/3733/which-optimization-method-to-use)
- [Optimization and Root Finding (scipy.optimize)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html)

Comment: This does not answer your question but the package https://pypi.org/project/mystic/ is very well suited to run a dozen (or more) dumb optimizers in paralell to explore local minima of surfaces. Have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geFER2oVvvU

Comment: Another package: https://github.com/JuliaIntervals/IntervalOptimisation.jl

Answer (score 1):

You can not make the basin-hopping algorithm find the global optimal point. Basin-hopping algorithm offers no guarantees of optimality.

There are common techniques for increasing the chances of finding global optimal point:

- Run the algorithm for longer.
- Progressively reduce the “temperature” parameter.
- Progressively reduce the `stepsize` parameter.
- Increase `niter_success` which increases the number of iterations without a change in global minimum candidate.
- Try different random seeds.